# Difference between DNNLinearCombinedEstimator, Regressor, Classifier? (Tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow

Looking at this link:
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.1/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/DNNLinearCombinedEstimator

I see

- DNNLinearCombinedEstimator
- DNNLinearCombinedRegressor
- DNNLinearCombinedClassifier

But there's little description about when each should be used.

Any info on this? Thanks in advance.